# Git script on windows

Tags: git, bash

Before git for windows was upgraded to `version 2.x.x` I was running scripts by simply creating a file with name `pull` and inside it I was putting something like `git pull origin master`. It was running normally, after I made format and install latest version of git it don't support that scripts any more.
The error I have is: `bash: pull: command not found`. I have tried to add `.bat` and `.sh` to those files, and that didn't work out.

## update:

Now i have in the file `pull` content:

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull origin master
```

To run that script i need to execute on terminal `./pull`. Can i somehow use that script without `./`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does work in Windows is creating a script called `git-xxx` (no extension).
For instance: `git-mypull`.

In that script, you can write a regular bash script, starting with `#!/bin/bash`.
It will be execute in the [mingw-64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) shell session which comes with the [latest Git for Windows 2.5.x](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

You call that script with `git xxx` (note the space): `git mypull`.

---

> Now I have in the file pull content:

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull origin master
```

> To run that script I need to execute on terminal `./pull`.
>   Can I somehow use that script without `./`?

Yes, as long as pull is in one of the folders referenced by `echo %PATH%`.
Then a simple pull would work.

Comment: Sorry for delay, it didn't work for me, and generally i didnt like to use git-

Comment: @GoncharDenys if `git-mypull` is referenced by your `%PATH%`, it will work, I promise. I use that all the time, from a regular DOS session.

Comment: @GoncharDenys I have edited my answer to address your update

Comment: Ok, your answer work too. I have did what i needed in my answer, so you can check if you want.

Answer (score 1):

That did the trick:
`printf '#!/bin/bash\ngit pull origin master' > ~/bin/pull` . I pasted generator code, just in case. it could be just file in the folder ~/bin in your user folder. Before you run that script, you should create folder bin. Also you can modify scripts to file you need. On the script i have pasted, when you write in terminal `pull` it start `git pull origin master`